# Distribution of sum of absolute values of 2D Gaussian

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

It was a while back I read probability theory and I've stumbled on a question in my work I'm not to sure about.

I have a position **a**=(x,y)+**g** with a added 2D Gaussian noise **g** $\in \mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol\mu,\,\boldsymbol\Sigma)$. I have a function similiar to:

f= ||**a**-**b**||-||**a**-**c**||  where **b** and **c** are two constant vectors.

I need to find the distribution of f. Anyone who can help me with this? Would be much appreciated!